# Objective-C: NSMutableString error

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablestring

I keep getting an error with this code, the app is telling me I am trying to mutate an object which is not mutable. Can someone take a look and explain what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

```
thisrow = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", startPointX2];
NSMutableString* setCoordStr = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[setCoordStr appendFormat: thisrow];

if(w==1) {
    thiscol =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", endPointY];
    [setCoordStr insertString:thiscol atIndex:[setCoordStr length]];
 } else {
    for(startPointY; startPointY<endPointY+1; startPointY++) {
        thiscol =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", startPointY];
        [setCoordStr insertString:thiscol atIndex:[setCoordStr length]];
    }
 }

NSLog(@"%@ ", setCoordStr);
```

Comment: Can you be more specific as to which line is failing?

Comment: Can you paste the exact error? "Trying to mutate an object which is not mutable" could be a number of things, and it's hard to guess which without the specific error information.

Comment: This ^. And the exact line on which the error occurred would be useful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could used `appendString:` instead of your first `appendFormat:`and your `insertString:atIndex:`

Comment: Could. But doesn't answer the question.  Of course, there isn't enough info to answer the question in the first place.